# search and remove string with variable parameters

Tags: macos, bash, perl, sed, terminal

i need to remove strings from a text file using command line on OSX.

the string will have some permanent features but have arbitrary digits.

i want to remove every variant of :-

```
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
```

This string has varying values but i want to remove it leaving only the relevant information in the sections labled:-

```
 PAttern1 :
 Code :
 CodeHash :
 Result :
```

the following MOCK procedure needs to happen

```
 for each line{
if string contains [%d%d%d.%d%d Kkey/s][total %d%d%d%d%d%d%d][Prob %d.%d%][%d%d% in %d.%dh]  (where "%d" is decimal value){

delete string and line

}
else if !contains {

 move down 1 line.
}
{
```

with the below text only the patterns and hashes should be saved to the text document

```
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]



            PAttern1: i want to keep all the text after pattern and all the code until the next line of processing including hash
            Code : aksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsd

            CodeHash : e3287cb701f336a628885e66d17e38f2

            Result : D0B6789D4E0ACF39A8C24B424C0060FFFF2DA857



            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]

            PAttern2: i want to keep all the text after pattern and all the code until the next line of processing including hash
            Code : qwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrq

            CodeHash : 05bfabd43ff6c85a8fa2d3347d828c4b

            Result : 165B6CA902E567959C9BB599FABEB3998B21E31F


            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.15 Kkey/s][total 2999999][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [370.02 Kkey/s][total 3000368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [323.02 Kkey/s][total 3001368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [389.02 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.06 Kkey/s][total 3003368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [300.01 Kkey/s][total 3004368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [379.02 Kkey/s][total 3005368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [279.02 Kkey/s][total 3006368][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
            [179.02 Kkey/s][total 3007898][Prob 0.0%][50% in 7.8h]
```

leaving the resulting text document to look like this:-

```
            PAttern1 : i want to keep all the text after pattern and all the code until the next line of processing including hash
            Code : aksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsdaksjhdakjsdhakshdkasdhkashkjahsd
            CodeHash : e3287cb701f336a628885e66d17e38f2
            Result : D0B6789D4E0ACF39A8C24B424C0060FFFF2DA857
            PAttern2 : i want to keep all the text after pattern and all the code until the next line of processing including hash
            Code : qwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrqgfqwfufiyfoqywfofqwytrq
            CodeHash: 05bfabd43ff6c85a8fa2d3347d828c4b
            Result : 165B6CA902E567959C9BB599FABEB3998B21E31F
```

i have used sed to remove single characters like so:-

```
 sed -i '' 's/%/\ /g' file.txt 
 sed -i '' 's/\[/\ /g' file.txt
 sed -i '' 's/]/\ /g' file.txt
 sed -i '' 's/Kkey\/s/\ /g' file.txt
```

while this works for the symbols i cant guess the numbers or sed out numbers incase they are within the the important strings and sed replaces it!

with the above routine in mind how would you approach this??

many thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` with `-v`:

```
grep -v 'Kkey/s.*total.*Prob' < input > output
```

Or if you want to remove blank lines too:

```
egrep '^[ \t]*(PAttern1|Code|CodeHash|Result) : ' < input > output
```

Comment: the egrep seems to work the best. can i use it inline so it does not need to make a new file? if i do

     < ~/Desktop/file.txt > output ~/Desktop/file.txt 

it leaves a blank file.

Comment: Can't do inline, but you can write to a temporary file, then replace the original: `egrep '^[ \t]*(PAttern1|Code|CodeHash|Result) : ' < ~/Desktop/file.txt > .output.txt ; mv ~/Desktop/file.txt ~/Desktop/file.txt.backup ; mv .output.txt ~/Desktop/file.txt`

Comment: iv just noticed in the actual example i am using there is a new line after the header so the script fails

Comment: eg.


`PAttern1:
examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1examplepattern1

`

Comment: `grep` and `egrep` have `-A` and `-B` switches so you can pull lines after or before.

Comment: Do you have `awk` installed?

Answer (score 0):

Perl command line solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\S/ &&  !m|\[\d+\.\d+ Kkey/s]\[total \d+]\[Prob \d+\.\d+%]\[\d+% in \d+\.\d+h]|' your_input_file > your_output_file
```

Comment: this seems to have no effect

Comment: That seems unlikely. When I run it, I get an output file containing the lines that you want. If it doesn't work for you, then perhaps there's something unusual about your environment that you're not telling us.